Android READ_CALENDAR permission is showing denied even if user is allowed it on Android 14
READ_CALENDAR permission is added in manifest.
When is started installed and started first time it shows permission pop. User will allow all permission
But when we check with code is permission lacking (NOT_GRANTED) it comes as true even if we allowed all permission at start.
final boolean lacking = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permission) ==  PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED;
        if (lacking) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "permission is not granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }

When app is force stopped and restarted then it will show permission as accepted
What could be the reason for this ?
IN GRADLE :
compileSDKversion : 33
targetSDKversion :33
tried on  sample app to reproduce this issue but not reproducible.

Have you followed the sample code closely? Are you sure that you don't accidentally check while the permission dialog is still open? Show us the code that requests and checks the permission and how they are connected.
